# Saving all images from a website in nested folders

Tags: html, images, backups, download

I've been asked by my supervisor to save all of the images from a website for backup purposes. I've been given admin privileges to the site, and there are 132 images, spread across several nested folders.

Here's a snapshot of some of the files inside one of the folders:

[image]

Each of these links to a file is actually to an html page with the image embedded in it.

Is there an easy way to download all of the images, possibly preserving the folder structure? I'm running Chrome on Windows 10. I don't think I have access to FTP on the site manager.

Comment: There's a number of different ways to do this: You can zip the root directory and then unzip it and it will contain the same directory structure; you could also download the root directory using an Explorer window on Windows and sign-in via FTP (e.g., `ftp://example.com/pub/uploads/`); you could use an FTP client that provides _recursive_ directory copying or mirroring,; or command line utilities like _wget_ might also be able to download recursive directories...

Comment: "Each of these links to a file is actually to an html page" - That maybe the case when viewing the site over HTTP (since the URL is probably rewritten). But what are we seeing the screenshot - that looks like an ordinary list of files? (Although, if there's just 132 images then you could have probably saved all the images manually in the time its taken to write the question and get solution...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have great success downloading entire sites with https://www.httrack.com/ (I have no association with it).

It may be possible to select only images.  But even if not, once you have the whole site, you should be able to delete all the "not images".